# Gradle doesn't find acra

Tags: android, maven, gradle, acra

I have an Android project in which I have been using ACRA 4.6.0 with a static jar file, all working fine. I have tried to change this to use the latest ACRA by the maven dependency in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.8.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

in my build.gradle. However this causes the build to fail with errors like:

```
CJApp.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import org.acra.ACRAConfiguration;
           ^
symbol:   class ACRAConfiguration
location: package org.acra
```

So far as I can tell gradle is not downloading anything for acra. I have tried adding `mavenCentral()` to the repositories list with no effect.

What else do I need to do, and is there any way of determining just what gradle has downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the class `org.acra.ACRAConfiguration` is included in the new version: `acra:4.8.5` which you're suddenly linking to? If not, this is a simple matter of incompatibility. In that case, it should be resolved if you step the version back to 4.6.0.

Have you checked that the build downloads the file from Maven Central? This should be clearly visible when giving gradle the `-i` flag - it will print every URL as it downloads them.

Comment: There were other imports reporting errors, and I thought I had tried changing it to `org.acra.config.ACRAConfiguration`, but I must have messed that up, because in the end that was all that was required. Your suggestions of trying an earlier version and using -i were helpful. I had reviewed the changelog and saw no mention of the config package being added.

Answer (score 2):

`ACRAConfiguration` has moved to `org.acra.config`. Just adjust your import.